# SqlAlchemy doubly linked tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-one

I have the following tables declared:

```py
uuidpk = Annotated[UUID, mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)]
user_fk = Annotated[UUID, mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('userschema.user_account.id'))]
str50 = Annotated[str, mapped_column(String(50))]

class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    """Subclasses will be converted to dataclasses"""
    pass

class ResidentialAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'residential_address'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'userschema'}

    id: Mapped[uuidpk] = mapped_column(init=False)
    address: Mapped[str50]
    user_id: Mapped[user_fk] = mapped_column(init=False)
    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='residential_address', default=None)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_account'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'userschema'}

    id: Mapped[uuidpk] = mapped_column(init=False)
    uname: Mapped[str50] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    birthyear: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True, default=None)
    current_residential_address_id: Mapped[Optional[UUID]] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('userschema.residential_address.id'), nullable=True, default=None)
    residential_address: Mapped['ResidentialAddress'] = relationship(back_populates='user', viewonly=True, default=None)
```

The idea in this toy-example is that I want the `ResidentialAddress` entries to retain their `user_id`, event if the user changes their `current_residential_address_id`.

I've tried setting the `foreign_keys` parameters, but I don't think I understand them well enough. Would anyone be kind enough to explain if this is possible/if it isn't?

I've tried setting the relationship in `ResidentialAddress` to:

```py
user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='residential_address', remote_side=id, foreign_keys=[user_id], default=None)
```

And the relationship in `User` to:

```py
residential_address: Mapped['ResidentialAddress'] = relationship(back_populates='user', viewonly=True, foreign_keys=[current_residential_address_id], default=None)
```

However, I get the following suggestion from SqlAlchemy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship ResidentialAddress.user could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.
```

I'm not sure if using the `remote()` annotation is the correct way forward, as I'm only finding examples where `remote` is used in self-referrential tables.

Comment: I'm not sure you can update only one side of the relationship, the whole point of relationships is to link objects. There might be a way to do something similar to what you're asking with [versioned rows](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/versioned_rows/versioned_rows.html).

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38836747/17676984).

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly my problem and a great solution. Thank you!